# Natbib \cite page numbering in italics and sorted \citetext citation

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm wondering if it is possible to alter the `\cite` command to always change the 'page number' section to italics, right now I'm using `\cite[\texit{p.~1}]{ref}`. Automation would be very welcome...

As for my second question, is it possible to automatically sort your reference when using the `\citetext` workaround? When using `\citetext{\citealp[]{}; \citealp[]{}}` it won't sort automatically, so again it would be wonderful to automate this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you employ at present?

Comment: I'm using natbib